# scheduled tasks don't show up in Get-ScheduledTask result

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012, octopus-deploy, windows-task-scheduler

I have defined some scheduled task using Windows Task Scheduler GUI under "" [default] path but when i run `Get-ScheduledTask` in powershell, it does not return them. why?

I have tried with `Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "MyTaskName"` with one of my task name but it comes up with "No MSFT_ScheduledTask objects found with property 'TaskName' equal to 'MyTaskName'"

Actually I have tried https://library.octopusdeploy.com/step-template/actiontemplate-windows-scheduled-task-disable but it doesn't work so I have tried running script directly.

**UPDATE**
I have found the following script to get task list on http://www.fixitscripts.com/problems/getting-a-list-of-scheduled-tasks:

```
# PowerShell script to get scheduled tasks from local computer
$schedule = new-object -com("Schedule.Service")
$schedule.connect() 
$tasks = $schedule.getfolder("\").gettasks(0)
$tasks  | Format-Table   Name , LastRunTime    # -AutoSize
IF($tasks.count -eq 0) {Write-Host “Schedule is Empty”}
Read-Host
```

Comment: What does "schtasks /query /v" in a command prompt return? Do you see your task?

Comment: @DavidBrabant it returns a long length of information which is difficult to find an specific task name in it.

Answer (score 15):

## UAC

The result is likely affected by [UAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control). To see everything try right clicking the PowerShell icon, select `Run as Administrator` and then run your `Get-ScheduledTask` command again and see if that changes anything.

**Further reading:** http://david-homer.blogspot.co.uk/2017/10/not-all-scheduled-tasks-show-up-when.html

Comment: When I try to run the  Get-ScheduledTask  from a terminal opened with "Run As Administrator" I alwas get the error `Get-ScheduledTask: Catastrophic failure `. I get the error in Powershell 1 and 7

Comment: Sounds like an issue with one of the Scheduled Tasks themselves. Do you get the error when running the task scheduler user MMC? I'd take a look at the following folder.

c:\windows\system32\Tasks

You likely have a corrupt task file in this folder.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using a com object? This code works for me:

```
# FOR A REMOTE MACHINE
$s = 'SERVER_NAME' # update this with server name
($TaskScheduler = New-Object -ComObject Schedule.Service).Connect($s)


# FOR LOCAL MACHINE
($TaskScheduler = New-Object -ComObject Schedule.Service).Connect()

#now we can query the schedules...
cls;$TaskScheduler.GetFolder('\').GetTasks(0) | Select Name, State, Enabled, LastRunTime, LastTaskResult | Out-GridView
```

This code will retrieve a particular task and enable it:

```
$task = $TaskScheduler.GetFolder('\').GetTask("TASKNAME")
$task.Enabled = $true
```

Comment: the first one is not working with '.' and neither without it. with '.' it gets the following error _Exception calling "GetFolder" with "1" argument(s): "This operation is supported only when you are connected to the server"_

Comment: the second one is getting the following error: _Exception calling "GetTask" with "1" argument(s): "Access is denied._

Comment: Sorry, not at a windows machine now. Try running in an elevated PowerShell session. Also, for a local task, the syntax needs to be slightly different - see my edit.

Comment: Again with the lastest changes, the same error _Exception calling "GetFolder" with "1" argument(s): "This operation is supported only when you are connected to the server._

Comment: Apologies, @mehran. You still need to connect, which I didn't test. See my latest edit.

Comment: I only get one task with `.GetTasks(0)`, and there are many others.

Answer (score 2):

When running `Get-ScheduledTask` from a user-level prompt, even if the user is an administrator, they will see only the tasks that they can read with user-level permissions. Seeing them in the TaskSchd.Msc window indicates that program is running with different permissions.

Therefore, running a PowerShell prompt as administrator solves the problem.

The same issue occurs when using SchTasks.exe from a command prompt.